# JDBC through JSP

Tags: jsp, jdbc

I was trying out a basic code to connect to DB using JDBC through a jsp page and display the results.

This is the jsp page I m facing problems:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=US-ASCII"
  pageEncoding="US-ASCII"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<b><u>Welcome page</u></b><br><br>
<%-- This is a JSP Comment before JSP Scriplet --%>
<%
 //Prints out to console
 System.out.println("Hello World in Console!");

 //Prints out to HTML page
 out.println("Hello World!");
%>

<form>

<a href="page2.jsp">Go to page 2</a> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using Eclipse,java 7 and have included the odbc7.jar in build path.
Still I am getting the following error when navigating to this page :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:190)
at org.apache.jsp.page2_jsp._jspService(page2_jsp.java:85)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have tried removing it adding again. And how did you add it ?

Answer (score 0):

Add your ojdbc.jar to apachetomcat\lib

Comment: this could rather be a comment

Comment: It's just a little answer.

Comment: As it turns out to be,I had put the odbc jar in the wrong path of tomcat.. Thanks a lot SanKrish and hurricane.. I can now connect and view the records in front-end.. :)

Comment: Can u apply my answer pls.

Answer (score 0):

You need the odbc7.jar as well in your WEB-INF/lib or on the application containers' class path.

Btw: Many containers provide container managed data sources which can be obtained from JNDI (something like InitialContext.doLookup("jdbc/yourDataSource"))